# What happens to Azure virtual machines software, if vm size is updated?

Tags: iis, azure, cloud

I use MS azure virtual machine. IIS running, hosting different web sites.  What happens ,when I update vm from extra small to small  ? Should I take a backup or nothing is required?There are some IIS bindings, should I move those settings ?

I think it is similar to gave more memory in vmware machine . But since it is vital for us, I am asking this question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VM will be gracefully shutdown and brought back up (most likely on a completely different VM host), so you will see some downtime as that transition occurs.  The actual data for your machine is stored in BLOB storage, not on the VM itself, so you don't specifically need to worry about a back up because you are making this change.  That said, if this is a production machine you need to be thinking about backups anyway.